# AWS LoadBalancer IAM Readonly Rule Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created custom IAM policy to have a read access to loadbalancer.  But I am getting error as...

> An error occurred fetching load balancer data: User:
>   arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/xxxxxxxx is not authorized to
>   perform: elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers

Bellow is the policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
        ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:000000000000:loadbalancer/*"
  }]
}
```

Please some one help with this.

---

Thanks

Sreekanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the `Describe*` actions do not support resource-level permissions.

For `Describe*` actions, you need to use `*` as your resource, otherwise, the commands will fail as not permitted.

Documentation and more information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/load-balancer-authentication-access-control.html#elb-resource-level-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I figured out. Bellow is the policies.

Read only AWS LB Access Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Allowing `Describe*` will not allow `Delete*`. This is not how IAM policies work. Such a deny policy is not required. IAM policies are "deny by default". So unless there is an allow statement for `Delete*`, it won't be permitted. The exception is if there is **another** policy or Managed Policy applied to the user or load balancer that is allowing `Delete*`.

Comment: No, I have two more policies attached to the user.  I can post them in some time.

Comment: Policy1..... {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Region": "us-west-2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Policy2.....{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ECUnrestricted",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticache:Describe*",
                "elasticache:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: None of these policies will allow change/delete on an ELB. My statement still stands: the deny policy is not required.

Comment: Sorry,  You are correct.  there was one more policy which was allowing it.  I figured it out. Thanks.  I am editing my answer.

Comment: @MattHouser Can you also help me on this.... I have created a second VPC in AWS which it is not a default VPC which we know it. I have three subnets in that second VPC. The issue is that, when I try to launch a ec2 with the second VPC I am not getting "No preference (defualt subnet in any Availability Zone)" option at the Subnet select column. I have to chose any of the three subnets in the VPC. I not sure if I missed anything while creating the secondary VPC or subnets. As I am getting the "No preference (defualt subnet in any Availability Zone)" option when I choose the default subnet.

Comment: Ask your new question as a new question on ServerFault.

Comment: Did. http://serverfault.com/questions/799621/aws-non-default-vpc-issue